# Piechart in QGIS - order colors

Tags: qgis, chart

In QGIS 3.14, I have a polygon layer that I use to show piechart - see screenshots. Everything is perfect except the drawing order of the different values (colors). I would like each pie (circle) to start at the top of the circle (noon) clockwise with the biggest value. Right now, it always has the same order: starting with orange (where applicable), than blue, red etc., as you can see e.g. in no. 14. In this case, it should start with blue at "noon", because the blue value covers almost 75% of the total amount. No 13 however is shown as I'd like to have it: orange representing the biggest class, it is also the first one.

I draw the piecharts from layer properties - charts tab, select piechart and than select the attributes I want to represent. Thus, the order is fixed. I suppose the order can be dynamically changed with the expression editor found in the tab where the attributes can be selected. However, I don't know how to write an expression that achieves what I want to do.

Thus, let's say I have the following attributes: orange, blue, red etc.
And the following features (as in the screenshot): 13, 14, 15....

The documentation is quite summary concerning [diagrams](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=pie%20chart#diagram-attributes):

> Generated attributes with Expressions can also be used.

Unfortunately, there is no more information. As a start, I tried `if ("orange" >  "blue" , "orange", "blue")` - but that does not work and even if it would, defining all cases would be too cumbersome as I have 11 different attributes (colors) to be represented (however, only about 3 to 5 per pie). How can the the colors (classes) be ordered, starting with the biggest and going to the smallest value?

**Edit**

I tried this expression as well:

```
array_get (
    array_sort (
        array(  
            "orange" , 
            "blue" , 
            "red" , 
            [... and so on ...] )
    ,false),
0)
```

This works fine to order my values acording to size, but assigns each time the same color for the first pie - bit the biggest category is not always of the same attribute (color).

Screenshot: no. 13 is correct (biggest valua at the beginning), no. 14 is not - here, blue is the biggest pie and should be the first one  - starting at noon, going clockwise:
[image]